# Best way to logout user using OAuth 2.0 api

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am new to OAuth 2.0. I have created an api that use OAuth 2.0 for authentication. Now, I am trying to use the api myself. But I am not sure how I logout an user after they click logout button. My question is do I need to delete the access token after they click logout or remove the user session. I am using password grant type.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to not allow user to use the app before log-in again you have to delete the access token from database so the token will be invalid, otherwise removing session without the access token will not invalidate the access token, you can try it by your-self, another point if you are using password grant type, so you are not using browser it should not be there any session.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sending GET requests to addresses "https://accounts.google.com/Logout?continue=http://google.com" to logout from Google, to "https://login.live.com/oauth20_logout.srf" to logout from Microsoft, and "https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?method=delete" for Facebook. Microsoft additionally needs redirect_uri and client_id parameters.

I think the token is not valid anymore after this request, but I haven't tested.

Answer (score 0):

1. Server Side To Do : Delete **access_token** and **refresh_token** from database .
2. Client Side To Do : Clear data from **localStorage** or **sessionStorage** or **cookie** from browser